# How to add a windows XP partition to my Ubuntu computer (which used to be XP)?

Tags: dual-boot, 16.04, partitioning, windows, windows-xp

I used to have XP and Vista on and old Laptop a friend gave me. It came like that. The laptop ran very slowly, though, so I decided to install Ubuntu on it. But, unfortunately, I now decided that I would like to play games on it, and Wine annoys me. So what I would like to do now, is add a Windows XP partition to the computer. How would I go about doing this? (Yes, I have an XP CD).

Comment: Have you tried sticking in the Windows XP CD and booting off of it?  You may have to go into the BIOS and enable booting from CD.  Otherwise, are you having any specific issues or do you have any specific questions?

Answer (score 0):

Use GParted, or any partition manager to shrink (if necessary) a partition on your harddrive. Format this partition as NTFS. Be aware that shrinking partitions can cause loose of data!

Next insert the WinXp CD and boot from the CD, and install WinXP on the partition you just created.

The GRUB boatloader will be overwritten by the Windows bootloader, so you will need to boot an ubuntu Live ISO. [Look here for more details](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows)

Comment: I found out that the major issue was my XP CD just didn't want to work with the computer for some reason. It may have been too old. I was lucky enough that Microsoft provided me with the CD for free..